# List of ID's as field in row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, list

I have two tables: One is big, expanded, it's `table_news` and one is very simple, with just two fields: `id` and `name` and it's called `table_categories`. So, it's obvious that I want to have some categories for every news. I know I can create a new table: `table_news_categories` which will contain something like: `id`, `news_id`, `category_id`. But for me it's a little overstatement. Can't I have a column like `categories` in `table_news`, which would be an "array" of categories' IDs? Wouldn't it be much simpler and easier to deal with?

Comment: This isn't exactly a question that involves solving a programming issue or is it? It's very unclear for me.

Comment: I want to ask if there is any possibility of handling array of IDs as an column and to know if it's good practise or not, and if it's good: if is it comparable to solution with additional table.

Comment: Ok. Now I think I understood your question as well. Answered.

Comment: _“Wouldn't it be much simpler and easier to deal with?”_ – no, it won’t. You might think it was for simpler queries, but as soon as you want to “do more” with your data, you’ll realize it is in fact very limiting. Normalization is there for a reason.

Comment: No. See normalization.

Answer (score 0):

If you want flexibility in your database you should have a ***link-table*** table

```
table_news 
table_categies
table_news_categories (linktable that links the above table together)
```

If you don't need the flexibility, you can always add a ***FORIDCategory*** or similar field in the `table_news` - table that creates the relationship between the tables.

```
table_news 
table_categies
```

By experience I would say the most preferable way is to add another (link)table from scratch. It might seem like unnessecary in the beginning but if the database grows you would certainly need it. It's harder to change the database-structure later on when having a lot of data in it.

**Example:**
You have 100 news now separated in 10 categories. In about half a year you may have 10.000 news. Now you would want to have two categories for some news. Then you would have create the link table, create all relations based on the ***FORIDCategory***-value into the new link table and then remove the ***FORIDCategory***-field and remain all the integrity of the database.